# QTableWidget - setCellWidget, doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add my custom widget as cell wigdet in QTableWidget object, but it doesn't wark at all, and I cannot solve it. Here is my code:

```
QTableWidgetItem* tableWidgetItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
ui->tableWidget->setItem(1,0,tableWidgetItem);
LineEdit* lineEdit = new LineEdit();
lineEdit->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,0,lineEdit);
```

I can determine that it doesn't work because my custom context menu didn't show up. Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you connect the context menu signal to a slot which is not calles? Could you test this behaviour with a different widget like a standard `QCheckBox` or something which is clearly visible instead of some custom implementation of the lineedit which we do not have

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time. I mistakenly thought that column headers are row number 0, and I tried to add custom call widget in doesn't exist row.